# R: ggplot. Axis labels in a boxplot for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using a for loop to create multiple box plots for a large dataset I have (320269 observables of 170 variables).

For this I am using the following code to generate the boxplots:

```
nm <- names(data)
for (i in 1:(ncol(data)-1)){
print(ggplot(data,aes(as.factor(data$Month),data[c(i)],color=as.factor(data$Month),aes_string("Month",nm[i])))
 + geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="black",outlier.shape=16,outlier.size=1,notch=FALSE))}
```

The graphs are printed in pdf and the boxplot itself comes out correctly, but something goes wrong with the axis labels.
No matter what I try, I get the x-axis label: `as.factor(data$Month)`, and on the y-axis: `data[c(i)]`, instead of "Month" on the x-axis and the actual column-names from the dataset on the y-axis.

What am I missing?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried adding something like `+ xlab("Month") + ylab(colnames(data)[i])`

Comment: Why are they two separate mapping in your `ggplot()`?

Comment: Thanks Bea, that helped!

Comment: @Bea could you please write down your solution as a "solution" and not simply as a comment? So that could help others... And by the way first result from Google is http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-title-main-axis-and-legend-titles (Searched for: "add labels to axis boxplot R ggplot")

Comment: thanks @fasttouch, I just added it

Comment: Thanks. In this way someone else will find it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify x and y axis labels by `+ xlab()` and `+ ylab()`

```
for (i in 1:(ncol(data)-1)){
  print(ggplot(data,aes(as.factor(data$Month),data[c(i)],color=as.factor(data$Month)))
        + geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="black",outlier.shape=16,outlier.size=1,notch=FALSE)
        + xlab("Month")
        + ylab(colnames(data)[i])
  )
}
```